# Error: restricted_client when authorization Youtube API V3

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I got this error when I create new client secret in new project.

> 403. That’s an error.
>
> Error: restricted_client
>
> Unregistered scope(s) in the request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
>
> Request Details
>       access_type=offline
>       response_type=code
>       client_id=487794563386-mujtj6b5iatnmvdailldn468gg028p8g.apps.googleusercontent.com
>       redirect_uri=http://localhost:61515/authorize/
>       scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
>       That’s all we know.

How could I fix that ?

Comment: Your getting this in the Google developer console?   This doesnt look like an error that google would display there.   This looks like an error you are getting from authenticating your application.

Comment: Yes, It's error when I open link to authenticating my application. I think google have just update, because don't have error yesterday

Comment: Google doesn't have access to update your application.  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Having the same problem as well and this was working fine yesterday. Luckily just doing some beta testing on an app but can't imagine if this was happening with a live app. C'mon Google, what changed and how do we fix?

Comment: I also get this error now when requesting access to the https://mail.google.com scope. "403 restricted_client". This is the only place I've seen a reference to restricted_client anywhere. I also didn't change anything in my application.

Comment: Old project won't get that error. Google just update for new project in Google Console

Comment: I am facing this error too. Since I am in the development phase of my application, I wasted few hours thinking it was the issue with my code..

Comment: @VinayakBhat yeah same here... 

How can we get information about this!? I'm stuck!

Comment: This post shows a similar problem with google drive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507417/error-restricted-client-using-google-drive-api. To repeat, just follow the tutorial linked. Definitely on Google's end so I guess we just wait until they fix it? Not good that bronze users have no way to notify google with such a problem

Answer (score 0):

403 errors are errors with the users access.  The user you are currently authenticated with does not have permission to do what you are trying to do in your case it appears to have something to do with the following scope.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Its hard to know what you are doing without seeing your code.  I suggest you attempted to authenticate your user again.   IF you changed the secret then its not going to work with a refresh token generated by another secret.

I am going to contact Google to be sure that there hasnt been any changes recently.  I cant see anything in the change logs myself.   There may have been a stealth change that they didnt release.

[Status](https://status.cloud.google.com/)

Comment: Don't think this is true as the user can't even log in. The code I am using is to authenticate a user and this happens from an iOS app with this method: [OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:presentingViewController:callback:]. This code used to allow the user to log into their account, now they just get the error. My error is slightly different as well: "404. That's an error. Error: restricted_client    Unregistered scope(s) in the request: https://www.gogglleapis.com/auth/youtube". Again, working the day before, how it doesn't. Google changed something.

Comment: typed wrong request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube; *now it doesn't. Perhaps it is with the user account but why doesn't this account not have access to the scope??

Comment: sorry for all the comments but I just tried logging out my google accounts on iPhone's Safari, cleared history and website data (cache) and get the same error. Don't think this has anything to do with user's access as this happens before a user enters any information. Has to be on developer side I think.

Comment: please edit your question and include some code I have not heard from my contact at Google yet

Comment: @DalmTo just added some code to the question. Let me know if you need more scope (no pun intended ;)