# error: restricted_client using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file using python to google drive. 
I started with the quick start shown here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python
Ive created the oAuth 2 client id and downloaded the credentials json file to my project folder.
However when I try to run the code, when it opens the browser to confirm I receive the following error:

```
Error: restricted_client

Unregistered scope(s) in the request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
Request Details

That’s all we know.
```

Ive tried changing the scope from

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
```

to

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

however I get the same error
I have also tried making a new credential and client id, still get the same error

can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507417/error-restricted-client-using-google-drive-api

Comment: Me too! Few hours ago started this tutorial. It does not work. However Google Plus API does with the same client.

Comment: I think this is something on Google's side since everything was working perfectly up until a couple of hours ago. Not sure what is causing it though.

Comment: Same for me, my offline app was working yesterday and now I get the same error!

Comment: Here's a link to an older, duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501811/error-restricted-client-when-authorization-youtube-api-v3. I tried editing the post with code to show the problem but it hasn't been approved.

Answer (score 1):

Update: at 18:18 UTC

Seems that it was an issue on googles end and now seems to be working again. I launch my python code and a browser window opens asking me to log in. I can log in and receive the message:

```
The authentication flow has completed.
```

Hope everyone else is able to get theirs working as well

Comment: Can confirm this is now working. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

This issue seem to be at Google's end . I faced similar issue with java SDK and many others have reported same issue today only while using YouTube API.

Comment: Agree. So how do we contact google when you only have bronze support options?