# Google Sheets API quickstart tutorial for python produces 403 error for valid OAuth2 credentials

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-sheets-api

I am following the [Google Sheets API quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) for Python (2.7) for a project I'm working on and I have hit a wall that I cannot figure out how to get past.

I followed the tutorial very closely and set up my OAuth2 credentials as they laid out, put the file in my quickstart.py script's directory, and renamed it client_secret.json.

However, running the script from terminal brings me to an *Error: 403 page*, with the error message **"Error: restricted_client"**

The treminal output from executing the script:

```
nik@debian:~/Documents/Misc/Py$ python quickstart.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access credentials.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))

Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets.readonly&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=(I probably shouldn't give this out)&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

I've tried touch'ing a credentials.json file in the script's directory, and that does stop the warning message from appearing, but it still doesn't populate the credentials file with anything.

It was my understanding that the script was supposed to create a credentials file for me, given the scope in the script and that this would need to be updated if the scope changed.

This is the missing piece in what has been a fruitful project so far, and I'm really at a loss. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
Commenters have pointed out that OAuth2 is broken for multiple people. In the meantime, while thats being sorted out, generate an API Key in your developer console and use this bit of code to auth your service module

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', developerKey=yourAPIKey)
```

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507417/error-restricted-client-using-google-drive-api for similar issue. It's seems to be on google side.

Comment: and this one, which was reported first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501811/error-restricted-client-when-authorization-youtube-api-v3

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue that comes from Google, yesterday I did that tutorial too, it worked perfectly but today I got the same issue than yours :

"403. That’s an error.

Error: restricted_client

Unregistered scope(s) in the request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
Request Details

That’s all we know."

We must be patient and wait for a fix.

Comment: Well, I'm glad I'm not crazy at least.

In the meantime, I will use this to auth my service module:
`service = build('sheets', 'v4', developerKey=key)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked for a brief moment: in the google console: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/  , 
pick the API , and enable the "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" and then pick the needed scopes from the popup that opens. It just seems that that setting gets disabled immediately when leaving that page...

Comment: It seems to have been resolved now, I just tried my script (needed OAuth for writing to a spreadsheet) and it gave me the correct prompt and everything, can you try it now?

Comment: Yes works like a charm now. <3. Thanks to G & others who fixed this.